# c# sqlcommand firing twice in the same iteration in foreach loop

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I am reading the rows from input table and for each row calling an api and inserting the response in the output table. Each row is unique in the input table and so is the api response, but when i write it to the output table the rows are duplicated.Below is the complete code

```
 string sqlconn, sqlquery;
            DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
            public void Main()
            {
                // TODO: Add your code here

                try
                {
                    sqlconn = Dts.Variables["User::varSqlconn"].Value.ToString();
                    sqlquery = Dts.Variables["User::varSqlquery"].Value.ToString();

                    using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(sqlconn))
                    {

                        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlConn))
                        {
                            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                            da.Fill(datatable);
                        }
                    }
                    foreach (DataRow record in datatable.Rows)
                    {
                        APIAddress.CallGoogleAPI((int)record[0], (string)record[1]);
/*the problem begins here
                        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(sqlconn))
                        {
                           if (APIAddress.FORMATTED_ADDRESS != null)
                            {
                                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, connection))
                                {
                                    connection.Open();
                                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ADDR_ID", APIAddress.ADDRESS_ID);
                                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ADDR_ONE", APIAddress.FORMATTED_ADDRESS != null ? APIAddress.FORMATTED_ADDRESS : DBNull.Value.ToString());
                                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@POSTALCODE", APIAddress.POSTALCODE_S != null ? APIAddress.POSTALCODE_S : DBNull.Value.ToString());
                                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                    command.Parameters.Clear();
                                }
                            }

                            else
                            {
                            }
                        }
                   }               
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Dts.Events.FireError(0, "ScriptTask", ex.Message, null, 0);
                }
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have duplicate rows in the datatable? seems more likely to me. Also, You will have better performance if you only set the parameters and execute the query inside the loop

Comment: @ZoharPeled no, I am 100% sure there is no duplicate records in the datatable.

Comment: @sab: what makes you think that it runs twice? The debugger or the result in the database? If the result in the database is different to the expected you should show us much more: the sql-query, the model, the expected and the actual result.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: the result in the database, i did a step into on each line of code and its the part i have highlighted in my question that fires twice

Comment: you open a new connection for each record and never close them?

Comment: @ZoharPeled no, I am 100% sure there is no duplicate records in the datatable. For each iteration the parameter values are different, so how do i set it outside the loop?

Comment: @BugFinder: I have the using statement there, wouldnt that close and dispose the connection? why do i need to do

Comment: why would you need to create a conneciton per record though surely it goes outside the loop.. would be far faster

Comment: [Just rearrange it like this.](http://rextester.com/HAE67304)

Comment: @BugFinder: I had that whole sql section inside a method and i just called that method in the foreach, but i still face the same issue

Comment: @BugFinder TBH it might not be that much faster. recreating the connection inside the loop might very well use the same underlying connection from the connection pool every time, so the only overhead is the .Net layer. Still it's a better alternative to create everything outside the loop.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: I get connection not closed error message, if I take your approach

Comment: Sorry, I left the `connction.Open` inside the loop by mistake.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: so i have to close and dispose the connection after the command.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: @ZoharPeled: i tried your version and also used close() inside the loop, but still same result

Comment: @TimSchmelter: i have edited the question and added the complete code

Comment: no, you should [open the connection before the loop](http://rextester.com/AWH67278) This should not solve the problem you are describing, but it's a better implementation for executing sql statements in a loop.

Comment: Unrelated tips: `SqlDataAdapter` is also disposable, so should be in a `using` block. Also once you've solved this problem, you may want to read "[Can we stop using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)".